# Argument for Grandi's Series equaling zero? Or flawed logic?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$1-1+1-1+1-1+.....=S$

$1-S=S=1/2$    (this is the reasoning I've learned before)

but if I try continuing this reasoning, I get

$$1-1+S=S$$
$$1-1+1-S=S=1/2$$
$$1-1+1-1+S=S$$
$$1-1+1-1+1-S=S=1/2$$
$$1-1+1-1+1-1+S=S$$
$$1-1+1-1+1-1+1-S=S=1/2$$
$$\cdots$$
$$S-S=S$$
$$S+S=S$$

Therefore, $S$ must equal zero? But that seems contradictory to what I've been taught? Is my logic flawed? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

The Grandi series is divergent. The reasoning that you claim to have learnt before is not quite correct as you cannot assign a particular value to a divergent series. A divergent series cannot be assigned a particular finite value this way.

Comment: Is it divergent or irregular?

Comment: @the_candyman It's obviously divergent. What does "irregular" mean here?

Comment: A sequence is irregular when there is no $L \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ such that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n = L.$

Answer (score 1):

Grandi's series is, of course, divergent, and what you have done only confirms it. Different ways of manipulating the series yield different results; the usually given sum $\frac12$ is the result of a certain *summation method* needed for some physical interpretation to make sense.

Comment: Is it divergent or irregular?

Comment: @the_candyman What is irregular?

Comment: A sequence is irregular when there is no $L \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ such that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n = L.$